# Error when running summary function

Tags: r, variable-assignment, summary

I have defined MV1 below with a value, and have used the MV1 in the output name. But when I try to run the summary function on my model output I get the following meesage `'Error: unexpected symbol in: "assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') <- model1 summary" '`

MVx is a value that is defined as a numeric in my code already, and MV1 equates to "_3" in my code.

```
MV = MVx+1
MV1= paste("_", MV, sep="")

assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') = model1 <- 
              glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=train70)

summary(Model_3) #Error occurs here
```

Would anyone know how to get around that? I'm not sure my `assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '')` is correct for what i'm trying to do even though I don't get an error messege.

Any help with will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `assign` is wrong. Note the `,` instead of `=` and you forgot the last bracket. And as pointed by [42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/42), you get rid of `model1 <-`

```
assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') , glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=train70))
```

Comment: Why not just: `assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') ,  glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=train70))`?

Comment: Thats great guys. Thanks for your help

Comment: one more quick question guys, the above code now creates my ouput called 'model_2'. When I try to run the following     summary(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '')) it doesnt generate the summary stats? How do I run the summary stats on the output from the output abover? Thanks alot for your help

Comment: @sandeep Your efforts at running R as a macro processor are holding back your progress in learning to use it effectively. Nonetheless R does have a corresponding function to `assign` that lets you get objects when all you have is a character vector created by paste. That function named .... wait for it .... `get`. You would be better served, however,  by creating a small example with a couple of examples and asking how to use lists of values. There are many examples on SO where similar advice can be seen.